# Using swap area when extracting a file or copying something into a external storage since Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: 19.04, swap, 19.10

In Ubuntu 19.04 swap area usage has an unexpected behavior. When extracting a file or copying files into external storage, OS starts to use swap area and does not release it after doing that task. It slows down the copying speed into the external drive and in the long term it may damage the hard drive.

How can I block this behavior of my OS? Note: It is happening since Ubuntu 19.04. Now I am on the 19.10 and problem still exists.

Initial memory allocation:

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           7861         900        5727         154        1233        6538
Swap:          1952           0        1952
```

Memory allocation after doing some file operations:

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           7861        1448         146         239        6265        5871
Swap:          1952          38        1914
```

Comment: What is the `free -m` output before and after such an operation?

Comment: It is 1952 when I just start my machine. then copied a file into my pen drive. Now its 1922. (Free of Swap) (Total of Swap is 1952)

Comment: Sure, I just updated question with a screenshots of memory allocations. Thanks

Comment: Please, do not paste images as long as you can. You should paste the ***text*** outputs into your original question. Having said that, the usage looks normal to me. This is my current output of the same command on my system after a few hours' heavy usage: `              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           7850        3672        1587         178        2590        3693
Swap:          4095         354        3741
`

Comment: Apology me, Thanks for your valuable guides. I just updated with my values.

Comment: Status please. Please see my answer, and if it was helpful, please accept it by clicking the checkmark and up-arrow icons just to the left of my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Swap is used to page out `recently unused, but active` pages of memory. This normally occurs under heavy usage.

If you look at your `free -h` command output, after the file copy operation, buff/cache went from 1233 to 6265, used as a **file buffer/cache**... and with only 8G RAM, something had to get paged out to swap, as you can see, RAM usage went from 900 to 1448, and swap went from 0 used to 38 used.

Absolutely normal.

Modern SSDs use wear leveling to prevent premature "aging". Swap is only used under heavy RAM usage.

Answer (score 0):

After some file operations, 38MiB is written to swap. This is *nothing*. It's probably some software that's not running actively, but just hogging memory. Ignore it. This is normal.

The kernel decided that the memory occupied by a non-running application could better be used to cache files than to hold that application, as it was inactive. That's probably true.

In general, don't worry about swap use as long as you have free memory to run whatever software you want, and the amount of swapping is low. You have plenty of free memory. Let the kernel handle swapping for you.

Comment: 38 MiB can be ignored, but my problem is This swap utilization aged my SSD hard drive. OS consume swap area continuously. (please correct if I'm wrong)

Comment: If it's written 38MiB to swap, it doesn't rewrite that unless it has to. And with modern SSD's you'll probably [buy a new SSD before you've worn out your old one](https://storageswiss.com/2014/05/19/is-it-time-to-stop-worrying-about-flash-wear-out/).

Comment: Therefore I restarts my machine. Restarts clear swap usage into the 0MiB usage.

Comment: When you reboot, you clear the swap, but that probably just leads to a rewrite of the swap space! Rewrites wear out SSD's. Static data doesn't.

Comment: @vidarlo It's important to read the conclusion in the link that you provided. Modern SSD's will last longer than the computer they're installed in. Also, yes, swap gets cleared on reboot, but it doesn't get "rewritten"... unless there's `recently unused, but active` pages of memory that require a swap out.

Comment: @MilanKarunarathne re: "*This swap utilization aged my SSD hard drive. OS consume swap area continuously.*) is incorrect. Modern SSDs use wear leveling to prevent premature "aging". Swap is only used under heavy RAM usage, and only to hold "recently unused, but active" pages of memory.

Answer (score 0):

I came across an article about swapping which is related to your question. I am posting the link as an answer here, instead of a comment, because using or not using swap is still a highly debated topic in Linux.

https://haydenjames.io/linux-performance-almost-always-add-swap-space/

The most important points in this article are:

> - Even if there is still available RAM, the Linux Kernel will move memory pages which are hardly ever used into swap space.
> - It’s better to swap out memory pages that have been inactive for a while, keeping often-used data in cache and this should happen when the server is most idle, which is the aim of the Kernel.
> - Avoid setting your swap space too large if it will result in prolonging performance issues, outages or your response time (without proper monitoring/alerts).

Towards the end of the article two kernel parameters `swappiness` and `vfs_cache_pressure` are mentioned, which you may want to experiment if you are still not satisfied with your current swap behavior.

---

Another good reference is:  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq